# How do I delete an organisation from Trello?

Tags: trello

I have made three organisations in Trello and I only need the one.

At the moment I am the only member of any of them.

How can I delete an organisation that I've created?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To delete an organization:

1. Go to the organization's page.  There are several ways to do this:

   - From a board in the organization, click the name of the organization (next to the board title)
   - Click your avatar in the upper right, click "Profile", open the organization from your "Organizations" list
2. Click "Account" on the right
3. Click "Delete this organization?" at the bottom
   [image: Delete this organization link]
4. You'll get a popup confirming that you want to delete the organization.
   [image: Delete organization confirmation]
5. Click "Delete"

**Note:** The [ability to delete organizations](https://trello.com/card/board/delete-an-organization/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c/4e7104ea06509c390404be46) went live on November 21, 2011.

Comment: The procedure is slightly changed, as the "Account" link isn't visible anymore on the organisation's page. The URL `https://trello.com/<organisation>/account` still works. See the Trello help page at http://help.trello.com/customer/portal/articles/984249-deleting-an-organization

Answer (score 0):

You currently cannot delete an organisation.

See [Trello Common Questions](http://blog.trello.com/trello-common-questions/):

> **Can you delete an organization?**
>
> No, not yet.

Comment: This answer is no longer current